# Building up Lat muscles without Chin ups, rowing or lat pull down

Tags: exercise, muscle

I have recovered from a back strain/injury. It was a pinched nerve. As part of my exercises I need to build my back muscles. The lateral muscles I am having trouble finding an excersise for. It seems that Chin Ups, Rowing and Lat Pulldowns are the popular methods.

I don't have equipment on hand to do those. I do have dumbbells, barbells and a bench with barbell holder. I also run treadmill and road/mtb bike ride.

What are other ways to build Lats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google "dumbbell rows." You brace yourself with one hand on your bench and row with the free hand. This is a pretty standard exercise. In your case you may want to be careful not to twist your body. Bent over barbell rows are another staple of "old school" body building/strength training. Again, lighter weight with stricter form may be the way to go. Check out "neutral spine" for these rows. You can support your head on something to keep a good bent over position. From this position you can also do *reverse dumbbell flyes* and for the rows you can pull the bar to your stomach or nipples to work different parts of your back. Check out http://www.ericcressey.com/no-chest-supported-row-no-problem
Barbells and dumbbells built some of the biggest backs in body building. Because of your injury you should probably focus on strict form - only the arms and scapula pull the weight, no body English. Feel free to ask for clarification or more links, Good luck and all the best.

Comment: The chest rows seem to be the one for me. thanks you

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: The chest rows were great yesterday.